# Remove the inner class

Tags: class, html

I have a structure like

```
<div class="inner">
   <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
```

How to remove the class of the inner div? That means my new structure will be

```
<div class="inner">
  <div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

**After edit**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inner .inner').removeClass('inner');
});
</script>
<div class="inner">
   <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. When you say you want to remove the inner class, how do you want to do that? Manually? Using JavaScript? Using PHP?

Comment: its very easy using JQuery(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)

Comment: @Naveen wikipedia link doesn't help here..

Comment: It might be in javascript or php or jquery. If so please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using jQuery

```
$('.inner .inner').removeClass('inner');
```

Comment: I did that according to you. But its not coming. Please check the updated code. Is there any wrong in my code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ApBMw/ if you see this here it works, you will notice the styles don't get applied to the inner div. If you comment out the javascript line, you will notice that both divs then have a border. What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this, as manipulating the DOM might not be what's needed for your end goal

Comment: actually I am using joomla 1.5 for my application and there one login form is there. But after login, I can find two divs are generating with the same class name. That's why I want to remove the inner div's class. Then my problem will be solved.

Comment: Does the login form redirect to another page? Or is it some kind of ajax success handler? If so then the above won't work as the element won't be on the page when that code fires. It sounds like the issue is more you want to change the html that joomla or this plugin is creating whether it's via a function or template (never used joomla so I'm not sure on the inner workings)

Comment: But unfortunately, it is not working in google chrome. Can u see once again please?

Answer (score 0):

As you've done, just remove the text that makes up the attribute and the value.

Did you mean programmatically, with a specific language? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: 2 years up and you should know that you should've posted this as a comment :)

Comment: I guess we can all suffer sarcasm, maybe I shouldn't have highlighted in this way that the question isn't a tech question at all. Technically I answered the question. 2 years, and, yes, I'm still trying to figure out how to handle people. (:

Comment: Life is hard, but we learn how to ask questions in general. Not just on the internet and not just here. There are some properties of a question that are fundamental whatever the medium and it's beyond me how such detail is left out. All in all, I gave a valid answer for the state of the question, but queried for more detail as a considerate citizen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/Manipulation/?rdfrom=http://docs.jquery.com/mw/index.php?title=Manipulation&redirect=no), it solves your requirement very easily.

Comment: don't just share the link, provide an answer like TommyBs did, I'll take away my -1

Comment: @Mr.Alien i up-voted TommyBs and provided the link for it.. I gave him the api for solving the problems as further useful information...

Comment: @Naveen ok I am taking my -1 but be sure if you want to provide a link, just comment on his answer or edit his answer :)